# Processing Timebased values

Tags: vbscript

I have a list of timebased values in the following form:

```
20/Dec/2011:10:16:29 9
20/Dec/2011:10:16:30 13
20/Dec/2011:10:16:31 13
20/Dec/2011:10:16:32 9
20/Dec/2011:10:16:33 13
20/Dec/2011:10:16:34 14
20/Dec/2011:10:16:35 6
20/Dec/2011:10:16:36 7
20/Dec/2011:10:16:37 16
20/Dec/2011:10:16:38 5
20/Dec/2011:10:16:39 7
20/Dec/2011:10:16:40 15
20/Dec/2011:10:16:41 12
20/Dec/2011:10:16:42 13
20/Dec/2011:10:16:43 11
20/Dec/2011:10:16:44 6
20/Dec/2011:10:16:45 7
20/Dec/2011:10:16:46 9
20/Dec/2011:10:16:47 14
20/Dec/2011:10:16:49 6
20/Dec/2011:10:16:50 11
20/Dec/2011:10:16:51 15
20/Dec/2011:10:16:52 10
20/Dec/2011:10:16:53 16
20/Dec/2011:10:16:54 12
20/Dec/2011:10:16:55 8
```

The second column contains value against each second. Values are there for complete month and for each and every second. I want to add these values:

- Per minute basis. [for 00 - 59 seconds ]
- Per hour basis [ for 00 - 59 minutes ]
- Per Day basis. [ for 0 - 24 hours ]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for Excel and a pivot table.

The trick is to parse the text date/time you have into something Excel can work with; splitting it on the colon will do just that. Assuming the value you have is in cell A2, this formula will convert the text into a real date:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(":",A2)-1))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH(":",A2)))
```

Then just create Minute, Hour and Day columns where you subtract out that portion of the date. For example, if the date from the above formula is in C2, the following will subtract out the seconds and give you just up to the minute:

```
=C2-SECOND(C2)/24/60/60
```

Then repeat the process for the next two columns to give you the hour and the day:

```
=D2-MINUTE(D2)/24/60
=E2-HOUR(E2)/24
```

Then all you have to do is create a pivot table on the data with rows Day, Hour, Minute and value Sum(Value).